# Designing Relational Survey Questionnaires Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, database-design

I'm trying to build a simple sql database for following access database. Currently there is no relationship and I just have two tables male and female with 6 sections in each form. How can I design it a better way so end user can connect to the database and analyze using STATA or SPSS ?

[image]

I'm really confused whether I should create one table with all fields or break down into different tables. The database is specific to this study only so I'm not looking for a generic survey database where user can create surveys and capture them. Any feedback or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/topic3.html, http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=384715 and http://ilovespss.blogspot.com/2007/01/getting-data-into-spss.html. If you need advice on your tables, you need to post table schemas, not images.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to move an Access database into SQL Server is to maintain the table structure as defined in Access.  This will facilitate loading and maintaining the data.  Presumably, someone thought about the table structure and you can leverage this information.

Of course, there are exceptions, and sometimes you do want to reorganize the data.  My preference is generally to do the porting first, be sure that works, and then do any reorganization.

I assume that the tables for MALE and FEMALE are split because the questions are gender-dependendent.

To access the data in SPSS or STATA, use a view rather than directly accessing the tables.  Without more information, I would guess that the view would be using UNION ALL to combine the data from the two tables.

Comment: But most of the questions in male and female are same(90%). In each table they have 6 sections. Is it worth creating table for each section ?